# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `headers_mails_index_path')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

El problema esta en el formulario porque he probado a hacer un H1 normal y me lleva perfectamente pero una vez que pongo el formulario me da el fallo

```
<%= form_for @campo do |f| %>

<div>       
    <%=f.label :primer_campo %>
    <%=f.text_area :primer_campo %>
</div>

<div>
    <%=f.label :segundo_campo %>
    <%=f.text_area :segundo_campo %>
</div>

<div>
    <%=f.submit %>       
</div> <% end %>
```

Eso es todo lo que tengo y @campo es la instancia del registro de la BBDD

Comment: Le falta el '<% end %>' al 'form_for'

Comment: Estaba en el código pero se me olvido copiarlo aquí. El fallo sigue estando pero gracias por ayudar

Comment: Ahh disculpame, voy a seguir revisandolo

Comment: Y como tienes definido en tu archivo de `routes.rb`? te sale el path al llamar a `rake routes`?